# C++ code is running in Windows 7 but not in windows 10

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a c++ code running in windows 7 but not works in windows10. It is working in MAC/LINUX. 
I am trying to parse a large hex file. My code loads in to array and then applies the business logic to generate the csv. 
The size of the file is 2.38GB. 
Below is the code.

```
bool readFile (string filename, char ** buffer  ,unsigned  int & sizeOfFile )
{
  ifstream inFile (filename.c_str (), ios::in | ios::binary);

  if (!inFile)
    return false;

  inFile.seekg (0, ios::end);
  size_t size = inFile.tellg ();
  inFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);

  *buffer = new char[size];

  cout<<"\n Length of the ARRAY= "<<size;

  inFile.read (*buffer, size);
  inFile.close ();
  sizeOfFile =  size;
  cout<<"File successfully read Press Any Key to Continue.. "<<endl;
  //getch();
  return true;
}
```

It is failing to load the file into array when I execute it in windows 10 under visual studio 2015 as well as under dev c++. It works perfectly in windows 7.

Comment: Don't spam tags! And read [ask].

Comment: Your windows 10 machine isn't 32 bits is it?

Comment: By "hex", do you mean "binary"? Hexadecimal representation is text.

Comment: Are you rebuilding the program for the Windows 10 target? Or using the same program as for Windows 7? Are you building a 32 or 64 bit program? Is the Windows 10 system matching that build? And can you please elaborate on the problem, the program doesn't *crash* it just doesn't load the data? Does it load *some* of the data? None at all? After the `read` call, what does `tellg` return? Does it differ from `size`? Are you perhaps getting an exception from the `new[]`?

Comment: When you single step the code, what line fails, what is the error code? We need more information than: _"It is failing to load the file into array..."_   Also is the platform 64 bit, is the build 64 bit?

Comment: Do you have read permission on the file in Windows 10?

Comment: My windows 10 machine is 64 bit. The file is in HEX format but can open as a character.

Comment: I tried executing the same windows7 exe on windows 10 , it did not work. I compiled the source code on windows 10 and still the same problem. The problem is that it is unable to do new/malloc of the array and load the file into it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
size_t size = inFile.tellg ();
...
*buffer = new char[size];
```

Looks like you're not creating a large enough space for the whole file to be read in. If the file were 10 bytes in size, you'd need to allocate 11 bytes as the null-terminated string needs an extra character at the end to store the `'\0'` character to terminate it. The fact that it works on some systems, but not others is pure luck as it means that on those systems there happened to be a NUL character at the right point in memory to properly terminate the string.

Comment: Binary data doesn't need a terminator.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be easier to use file mapping?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx

EDIT:
You mention below that you are using the same code on macOS and Linux. I'm more familiar with these platforms, where I would use mmap(). Effectively this automates the loading of data from the file to memory.

Otherwise, as mentioned above, you need to provide more information on the nature of the problem (32 or 64bit build, type of failure).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I have a c++ code running in windows 7 but not works in windows10. It is working in MAC/LINUX. I am trying to parse a large hex file. My code loads in to array and then applies the business logic to generate the csv. The size of the file is 2.38GB. Below is the code.

It is failing to load the file into array when I execute it in windows 10 under visual studio 2015 as well as under dev c++. It works perfectly in windows 7.

Comment: I think it is more of a compiler issue. I came to such conclusion when I could find that it  was exactly crashing afte 2GB. I also read in some forum that for 32bit computer 2 GB is the limit. If we can use a proper 64 bit compiler it should work. I tried using visual studio 2010 and If you change your project (under project properties, preprocessed definitions) to be WIN64, It can  load the file.

Comment: I found the reason,  the problem is with the compiler  Dev c++ is  not working for 64 bit in windows 10. When I compiled with  MS Visual Studio it worked.